# dynamic (based on prev protofield value) Protofield valuestring based

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I'm developing a wireshark plugin in lua.

I have a Protofield whose valuestring table changes based on the value of a previous field. I dont see a way to do that cleanly in the lua wireshark plugin I am developing.

e.g.

```
parent_type = Protofield.uint8("myProto.myParentField", "Parent", base.HEX, {"1", "2"}, 0xf0, "")
child_type = Protofield.uint8("myProto.myChildField", "Child", base.HEX, {"if parent 1, value 3 else 5", "if parent 1 value 4 else 6"}, 0x0f, "")
```

Now I want to be able to make the decision on the child_type field's valuestring based on what the parent_type's value is.

I was able to do an append_text to child_type in the *dissector:call* method but that is of the form

**.... ...1 = Child: (0x01) 3**

where I am looking for it to be (being a bit pedantic)

**.... ...1 = Child: 3 (0x01)**

If I use *:set_text* the entire text *".... ...1 = Child: (0x01)"* is replaced with *"3"*

I tried to use string lib operations but I am not able to get them to work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by *`"if parent 1, value 3 else 5", "if parent 1 value 4 else 6"`*?  

If the value of the parent field is 1, then is the child value supposed to be 3 or 4, and what impact, if any, does the child value itself have?

Answer (score 1):

you can write like this

```
parent_type = Protofield.uint8("myProto.myParentField", "Parent", base.HEX, {"1", "2"}, 0xf0, "")

child_type_for_p1 = Protofield.uint8("myProto.myChildField", "Child", base.HEX, {"3", "5"}, 0x0f, "")
child_type_for_p2 = Protofield.uint8("myProto.myChildField", "Child", base.HEX, {"4", "6"}, 0x0f, "")

if v_parent_type == 1 then
    packet_detail:add(child_type_for_p1, ...)
elseif v_parent_type == 2 then
    packet_detail:add(child_type_for_p2, ...)
end
```